# How to “Pre Fill” customer Name, Phone Address into textFields

Tags: ios, swift

I want to be able to have the option of "Pre Fill" selected textFields. Populate them by clicking on an icon that links to the phones contacts where i can select a contact and then it automatically enters their details into the textFields.

All textFields are on the same ViewController

Comment: You described your intent and provided code, but I couldn't find the actual question. What's not working the way you want? Please edit your original post.

Comment: After more time hunting through the code, trial and erro i now have the table with cells working , however how do i now make the cells editable by the user

Comment: also how to get the selection (can be more than 1 cell) to pass into the textfield in the 1st view controller. Showing the data from the table cells with a " ," between selected texts